# How to remove exact match result in MySQL LIKE operator?

Tags: php, mysqli

Is there any way to remove exact match result from  MySQL LIKE operator?

I have a column in a table that contain words like:

1. Abort
2. Aborticide
3. Aborticidium
4. Abortifacient
5. Abortion

So, when I query for "Abort", I just want to display related word for "Abort" not exact "Abort". I just want to remove it from result.

I use this simple MySQL query code:

```
mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM medi_words WHERE word LIKE '%$query%'");
```

Comment: Remove the Last % : "SELECT * FROM medi_words WHERE word LIKE '%$query'"

Answer (score 3):

You can use another condition in the query like so:

```
mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM medi_words WHERE word LIKE '%$query%' AND word != '$query'");
```

Comment: I would have used ``word NOT LIKE '$query'`` but it's exactly the same as your answer

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i a have another question. How can i display next 5 record or row after query result?

Comment: Hey Im glad it helped!  As far as your other question, we try to limit answering multiple questions per thread on SO.  So if you search the web and can't figure it out please post another question related to the topic of your problem.  If you want to restrict your results you would use the SQL term `LIMIT` or use a loop to iterate through your results.  Cheers!